# Change image's color/style into the color/style from another image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

For example, there are four images like below:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

How to change the colors of the objects in these four images into the grey one from the image below (please ignore the three axes in the middle)? In other words, after changing, the colors of the four images above should look like the one below.

If this is difficult, it is not necessary to follow the image below. As long as the four images above are uniformed with the same color (e.g., grey), it is also OK. Is there any way to do this? Thank you!
[image]

**Update:** I used `cv2` to get the contours and used `cv2.fillPoly` to fill gray color. It is almost there but after filling the contour lines disappeared as below. Can the lines be kept after filling gray color? Thank you!

```
import cv2  
img = cv2.imread("image.jpg")  
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  
ret, binary = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)  
 
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)   
cv2.fillPoly(img,[contours[1]],(128,128,128))
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: getting contours and using fillPolly function may help ?

Comment: Thanks @YunusTemurlenk. I tried the fillpoly function in cv2 library and have updated the results and problems in the post.

Comment: sure, after fillPolly; use  drawContours function to re-draw lines

Comment: Thanks @YunusTemurlenk. Could you post something so that I can accept the answer hhh :)